# login customer throw header are already set

Tags: magento-2.1, error, overrides, controllers, login

I created an Ajax call to login an user and return layout html. But I always get this error :

```
Exception: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/app/code/Interpack/Customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php:130) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 125 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/Applications/M...', 125, Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(125): setcookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b150d31bb10baec...', 0, '/', '', false, true) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(78): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b150d31bb10baec...', Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http.php(85): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setSensitiveCookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b150d31bb10baec...', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\SensitiveCookieMetadata)) #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http->sendVary() #5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/Response/HttpPlugin.php(25): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendVary() #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\Response\HttpPlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/interpack/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#12 {main}
```

So to did that I override the execute method of the loginPost controller :

```
public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        }

        $login = null;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        }
        if (!is_null($login)) {
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                        $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                        if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                            $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                            // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                            return $resultRedirect;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    $message = __(
                        'The account is locked. Please wait and try again or contact %1.',
                        $this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('contact/email/recipient_email')
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
        } else {
            // Load layout in function of the status of the user
            $this->_view->loadLayout();
            $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
            if ($this->customerIsLoggedIn()) {
                echo $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.popin.connected')->toHtml();
            } else {
                echo $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.popin.disconnected')->toHtml();
            }
        }
    }
```

if I call this function with this url for example : http://magento.lan/customer/account/loginPost?ajax=1&username=toto@gmail.com&password=Potato123

I get the correct HTML (the user is logged in, if a go in account page I'm connected as the right user) but I get bellow the error I give you at the top of the post.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add an `exit;` just after

echo $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.popin.disconnected')->toHtml();

and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: I solve my problem by returning my block html by JSON ;) But thanks it can be an another solution ;)

Comment: @Sji Joseph, this indeed works! can you explain why this solves the problem? What would be a permanent solution?

Comment: @Siju Joshep: Thank you, It solve my issue. Actually I am trying to display data which comes through json. If user is not login there is no any issue, But once I login then this issue will occurred. I just put exit; after my echo line. And problem solve. But what happen here that really don't understand. Can you please explain. "cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

Comment: It is due to `vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/Response/HttpPlugin.php:25` `$subject->sendVary();` Magento tries to add the magento vary after header are already sent. I reproduiced the same error with invoice pdf output.